# Question about Trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

How do I solve this:

If $A + B + C = \pi$ and $\sin \left(A + \frac{C} {2}\right) = 4\sin\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)$

Then $\tan\left(\frac{A} {2}\right)\tan\left(\frac{B}{2}\right) =\,\text{?}$

Comment: Please indicate what you have done so far and where you are stuck. This will help others better tailor their answers to your background and situation. It will also show them that you are interested in your question and not just trying to get someone to do your homework - StackExchange is not a homework site.

Comment: Begin with the work and mention source of  your difficulties when lot of help comes in.

Comment: thanks for the tips I will remember that next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

$$C=\pi-A-B$$

we get

$$\cos \left(\frac{A}{2} -\frac{B}{2}\right)=4\cos\left(\frac{A}{2}+\frac{B}{2}\right)$$

and from here we have with the addition formulas

$$\cos \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{B}{2}\right)+\sin \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\sin \left(\frac{B}{2}\right)=4 \left(\cos \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{B}{2}\right)-\sin \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\sin \left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\right)$$

Dividing both sides of this equation by $$\cos \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{B}{2}\right)$$

we get

$$1+\tan \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\tan \left(\frac{B}{2}\right)=4 \left(1-\tan \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\tan \left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\right)$$
Can you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, we need to eliminate $C$ by replacing with $\pi-A-B,$

$$\dfrac{\cos\left(\dfrac A2-\dfrac B2\right)}{\cos\left(\dfrac A2+\dfrac B2\right)}=\dfrac41$$

Applying [Componendo and Dividendo](https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/),

$$\dfrac{\cos\left(\dfrac A2-\dfrac B2\right)-\cos\left(\dfrac A2+\dfrac B2\right)}{\cos\left(\dfrac A2-\dfrac B2\right)+\cos\left(\dfrac A2+\dfrac B2\right)}=\dfrac{4-1}{4+1}$$

$$\iff\dfrac35=\dfrac{2\sin\dfrac A2\sin\dfrac B2}{2\cos\dfrac A2\cos\dfrac B2}=\tan\dfrac A2\tan\dfrac B2$$